# Pyspark round function not working as expected

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rounding

I have calculated tha acccuracy of the Naive Bayes model using MulticlassClassificationEvaluator module and I am trying to round it off to 2 decimal places. Below is the code for the same:

```
    print("Naive Bayes accuracy is: " + str(round(rf_accuracy,2)))
```

But I am facing the below issue:

---

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 print("Naive Bayes accuracy is: " + str(round(rf_accuracy,2)))

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyspark/sql/column.py in _to_java_column(col)
54             "{0} of type {1}. "
55             "For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' "
---> 56             "function.".format(col, type(col)))
57     return jcol
58

TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: 93.15707620528771 of type <class 'float'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.

I've searched a lot on google and went through the pyspark functions and examples, but with no luck. Not sure what am I missing. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If rfaccuracy is the column name of your dataframe then you have to do something like this

```
import pyspark.sql.functions aa f
df.select(f.round('rfaccuracy')).show()
```

Comment: Its not a column, its a variable calculated like this:   evaluator = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(labelCol = "label", predictionCol = "prediction", metricName = "accuracy")
rf_accuracy = evaluator.evaluate(predictions)*100

Comment: What is type(rf_accuracy)

Comment: rf_accuracy is a float

Comment: yeah..but not sure what is going wrong...I tried by hard coding the value for accuracy(a random float no.)..even then I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Try this print ('accuracy is {:0.2f}'.format(rf_accuracy))

Comment: Can you please tell me how to round multiple columns of a dataframe? I only see we can do it on specific column everywhere.